# Embedded Jetty Throughput

Tags: embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I want to know maximum throughput of embedded jetty server (9.4.5) including hardware details where such throughput is achieved.

I dont find this information in online. Planning to implement our project with embedded jetty.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: This kind of question is not well suited for stackoverflow.com (which has a focus on software development), have you tried https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com yet?

Comment: You can also ask on the [official jetty-users mailing list](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/jetty-users).

Comment: Not yet. I am new to this.

Comment: Thanks I will reach them